# Express, using same routes with different imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to make the a multi-language website. I've decided to go with data objects, to fill in all the text necessary. The routes I'm using for the 2 languages are exactly the same with only a difference in the import. Is there any way to make this happen without code duplication?

The templating engine is Express Handlebars, so if there is another solution for making a website multi-language, I'm open to implementing it :)
Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

The code in my routes for Sl language:

```
const express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router(),
    data = require("../Views/res/lang/sl");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    data.Home = setupDataObject(data.Home, req.originalUrl, "Home");
    res.render("homepage", data.Home);
});

router.get("/About", (req, res) => {
    data.About = setupDataObject(data.About, req.originalUrl, "About");
    res.render("About", data.About);
});

function setupDataObject(data, url, active) {
    data.current = url.substring(4);
    data.active = { [active]: true };
    return data;
}
module.exports = router;
```

And the English version

```
const express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router(),
    data = require("../Views/res/lang/en");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    data.Home = setupDataObject(data.Home, req.originalUrl, "Home");
    res.render("homepage", data.Home);
});

router.get("/About", (req, res) => {
    data.About = setupDataObject(data.About, req.originalUrl, "About");
    res.render("About", data.About);
});

function setupDataObject(data, url, active) {
    data.current = url.substring(4);
    data.active = { [active]: true };
    return data;
}
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a behaviour like `router.get("/:locale/About", ...` instead of your actual routing ?

Comment: Here I imagine you know the language, e. g. we have somewhere lang = [myLang]. Then you may be able to use:
```data = require(`../Views/res/lang/${lang}`);```

Comment: Can I get the "locale" variable at the imports section and how? If I can do that I'll love you forever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the locale in using with the url params, no ?

```
const express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router();


router.get("/:locale/", (req, res) => {
    const data = require("../Views/res/lang/" + locale);
    data.Home = setupDataObject(data.Home, req.originalUrl, "Home");
    res.render("homepage", data.Home);
});

router.get("/:locale/About", (req, res) => {
    const data = require("../Views/res/lang/" + locale);
    data.About = setupDataObject(data.About, req.originalUrl, "About");
    res.render("About", data.About);
});

function setupDataObject(data, url, active) {    
    data.current = url.substring(4);
    data.active = { [active]: true };
    return data;
}

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Any way of making this not having to require every route? It seems a bit wasteful, or am I just trying too hard here?

Comment: I think it's the best way. But in thinking, if your extract your routing in a router file, you can maybe prefix it by the prefix ':locale' ... But I prefer this one. The only problem you've to manager is to manage the real '/' route in order to choose which locale you've to use.

Comment: This is already in a separate file, in the server.js I'm using it like this, after your suggestion previously:
`app.use("/:locale", slRouter);`

Comment: Yep like this one, but I never try, it's an idea, I'll be pleased to know the result... O_O But a though, If it work, instead of treat the locale variable each time, you can use the app.params as a middleware : https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param

Comment: Hmm, I've thought about just substringing the original url and copying it in :P
I'll try to figure out this param link you've posted. I think it should be what I'm looking for. I'll report back on what I find..

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing this right. From the documentation, I think this should work:
`app.use("/:locale", slRouter);
app.param("locale", (req, res, next) => {
 console.log(`Loaded up language: ${locale}`);
 next();
});`
I get the error "locale not defined"

Comment: `(req, res, next) => { req.data = require("../Views/res/lang/" + req.params.locale); next(); }`  after you can directly use req.data as your localized data;

Comment: Thank you, this now works wonderfully and saved me a ton of duplication!